# Cannot pull image from insecure registry using Rancher's "docker-based development deployment"

Tags: docker, rancher

I have followed the instructions to set up a Rancher instance in a docker container as found here: https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/getting-started/installation-and-upgrade/other-installation-methods/rancher-on-a-single-node-with-docker

Everything is up and running, and I can pull images from docker-hub and run them successfully (verified by starting a job from the UI with `hello-world:latest` and it finishing successfully)

Now I want to run an image from our local image registry, which is insecure (it is on-prem and only internally accessible)

Whenever I try to run a job with one of these images, I get this:

```
Failed to pull image "our/registry/url/our-image:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "our/registry/url/our-image:latest": failed to resolve reference "our/registry/url/our-image:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://our/registry/url/v2/our-image/manifests/latest": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match our/registry/url
```

I have definitely added our registry URL to the host machine's `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, and have verified this by pulling and running the image on the host machine, which was successful.

I also tried going into the rancher container, creating the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and putting the same insecure registries into it. Then I restarted the container and tried again, and got the same issue

What am I missing here? As far as I can tell, the rancher container is just proxying the host machine's docker instance, and so it should still be allowing the same insecure registry information.